# Searching for repeated characters in a sequence of characters

Tags: programming-challenge, lisp, clojure

The following code solves this problem:

> The 3072 characters below contain a sequence of 5 characters which is
>   repeated. However, there is a twist: one of the sequences has a typo.
>   To be specific, you're looking for two groups of 5 characters which
>   share 4 of those characters. Enter the 4 shared characters below to
>   proceed.

Any suggestions on how it can be improved using idiomatic Lisp/Clojure?

```
(ns slurp.slurp)

(defn get-five [in]
  (if (> (.length in) 4)
    (subs in 0 5)
    nil))

(defn how-good [a b position goodness bad-position]
  (if (= position 5)
    (list goodness bad-position)
    (if (= (subs a position (+ 1 position)) (subs b position (+ 1 position)))
          (recur a b (+ 1 position) (+ 1 goodness) bad-position)
          (recur a b (+ 1 position) goodness position))))

(defn matches [a b]
  (let [x (how-good a b 0 0 -1)]
    (list (> (first x) 3) (last x))))

(defn remove-bad-char [in-string bad-index]
  (str (subs in-string 0 bad-index) (subs in-string (+ 1 bad-index))))

(defn sub-parse [left in]
  (let [right (get-five in)]
    (if (not (= right nil))
      (let [match-result (matches left right)]
        (if (first match-result)
          (let [bad-index (last match-result)]
            (println left "is a match. bad-position:" (last match-result) "ans: "(remove-bad-char right bad-index)))
          (recur left (subs in 1)))))))

(defn parse [in]
    (let [left (get-five in)] ;; as soon as we hit the ass end of the input string, get-five returns null and we stop trying to match.
      (if (not (= left nil))
        (do
          (sub-parse left (subs in 1))
          (recur (subs in 1))))))

(parse (slurp "/Users/clojure/challange.txt"))

;; https://www.readyforzero.com/challenge/491f97bc25574346aed237d43e7d0404
;; (answer is i2+r)
```

Comment: Actual URL of input data appears to be: https://www.readyforzero.com/challenge-data/2315ff7b4e1d47deb54e5457bd3334a9/1

Comment: this isn't common-lisp. tag is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, I've done the ready for zero programming challenge too... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd start bottom-up on this one if you want to do it in a slightly more idiomatic / functional style. Also it's good to get the data in Clojure sequences rather than strings as it makes it a bit easier to manipulate.

You're trying to work on groups of five adjacent characters so I'd set up a sequence of such adjacent groups:

```
; define some source data, right answer is "1235"
(def char-seq (seq "dfyfgvbufi12345idvdfhopshbsopgeobvufpdhbugphp123a5ghauoyhewqojbvrbon"))

; now partition into adjacent overlapping groups of five (with a step of 1)
(def char-groups (partition 5 1 char-seq))

; prove it works
(take 3 char-groups)
=> ((\d \f \y \f \g) (\f \y \f \g \v) (\y \f \g \v \b))
```

Now we want to define what a valid match means: in this case 4 characters should be the same in two groups being compared.

```
; helper function to count the number of true values in a collection / sequence
(defn count-true [coll]
  (reduce 
    #(+ %1 (if %2 1 0))
    0 
    coll))

; function to determine if exactly four characters are equal in two groups
(defn matches? [group1 group2]
  (= 4
    (count-true (map = group1 group2))))
```

Finally you just need to run the matches? function over all possible groups:

```
(def results
  (distinct
    (keep identity
      (for [group1 char-groups 
            group2 char-groups]
        (if (matches? group1 group2)
          (filter identity (map #(if (= %1 %2) %1 nil) group1 group2))
          nil)))))


results
=> ((\1 \2 \3 \5))
```

Comment: thanks mikera. I got to learn some new stuff:

partition
reduce
distinct
keep
indentity
filter 
map
for. 

btw, why did you need (keep identity ....) ?

Comment: I see that the keep identity is used to filter the nil's returned by:

 (for [group1 char-groups
    group2 char-groups]
   (println group1 group2)) 

But I can't understand where the nils come from when

    char-groups
  
Does not return any nils. Why is the for putting them in?

Comment: the (for ....) construct returns nils when there is no match via the if statement. This is an artifact of the way the for construct works (it creates a lazy sequence over all possible combinations of char groups). Incidentally this is also why you need the "distinct" because it will match the char-groups twice (once in normal order, once in reverse order)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version.  Works on any seq (not just strings) and is fully lazy.

```
(def data (slurp "data.txt"))

(defn same-pos 
  "Return all the elements of xs and ys that match, position-wise.  e.g.
  (same-pos [\\a \\x \\c] [\\a \\r \\c]) returns [\\a \\c].  Returns nil if xs
  and ys have different lengths."
  [xs ys]
  (when (= (count xs) (count ys))
    (filter (complement nil?) (map #(if (= %1 %2) %1) xs ys))))

(def answer
  (let [ps (partition 5 1 data)]             ; build seq of sliding 5-tuples
    (->> (for [x ps y ps] (same-pos x y))    ; n^2 FTW
         (filter (comp (partial = 4) count)) ; 4 of 5 positions must match
         (first))))

(println (apply str "Answer: " answer))  ; will print "Answer: i2+r"
```

**Update:** I didn't read other answers beforehand (wanted to figure it out myself), but it looks like I've got basically the same thing as [mikera](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/how-can-i-improve-this-code/3480#3480).  So maybe not a whole lot to learn here :)